# how to make closing JPanel trigger a method

Tags: jpanel

I got an example of JPanel from the Oracle tutorials
I see it uses a default method to close the window

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

what I want is the act of closing the window when clicking the close button, to trigger another method.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29

Answer (score 0):

This code will execute when you attempt to terminate Swing or console programs.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //code goes here
    }
});
```